# Error with update-initramfs

Tags: initramfs, busybox

I am having trouble when running update-initramfs in an Ubuntu 14.04 server.

It all started trying to recover a non booting system.

From a chroot console (from an Ubuntu 14.04.3 desktop CD), when I run "update-initramfs -v -u -k all" I get the following:

```
dpkg: unrecognized option '--compare-versions'
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) multi-call binary.

Usage: dpkg [-ilCPru] [-F OPT] PACKAGE

Install, remove and manage Debian packages

        -i,--install    Install the package
        -l,--list       List of installed packages
        --configure     Configure an unpackaged package
        -P,--purge      Purge all files of a package
        -r,--remove     Remove all but the configuration files for a package
        --unpack        Unpack a package, but don't configure it
        --force-depends Ignore dependency problems
        --force-confnew Overwrite existing config files when installing
        --force-confold Keep old config files when installing
```

many times, then

```
Available versions:  3.13.0-24-generic 3.13.0-46-generic 3.13.0-55-generic 3.16.0-51-generic 3.19.0-25-generic 3.19.0-31-generic
Execute: /usr/sbin/update-initramfs -u -k "3.13.0-24-generic" -b /boot -v -t
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
```

then the same error, then

```
dpkg: unrecognized option '--print-architecture'
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) multi-call binary.

Usage: dpkg [-ilCPru] [-F OPT] PACKAGE

Install, remove and manage Debian packages

        -i,--install    Install the package
        -l,--list       List of installed packages
        --configure     Configure an unpackaged package
        -P,--purge      Purge all files of a package
        -r,--remove     Remove all but the configuration files for a package
        --unpack        Unpack a package, but don't configure it
        --force-depends Ignore dependency problems
        --force-confnew Overwrite existing config files when installing
        --force-confold Keep old config files when installing

modprobe: unrecognized option '--set-version=3.13.0-24-generic'
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) multi-call binary.

Usage: modprobe [-alrqvsDb] MODULE [symbol=value]...

        -a      Load multiple MODULEs
        -l      List (MODULE is a pattern)
        -r      Remove MODULE (stacks) or do autoclean
        -q      Quiet
        -v      Verbose
        -s      Log to syslog
        -D      Show dependencies
        -b      Apply blacklist to module names too
```

then, other similar errors from other commands. Then I get

```
Adding binary /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
Adding binary /usr/lib/initramfs-tools/bin/wait-for-root
Adding library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1
Adding library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Adding library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcgmanager.so.0
Adding library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih.so.1
Adding library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih-dbus.so.1
Adding library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3
Adding library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
Adding library /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Adding library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
Adding binary /sbin/modprobe
Adding binary /sbin/rmmod
Adding binary /sbin/blkid
Adding library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1
Adding library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1
Calling hook compcache
Calling hook fixrtc
Adding binary /bin/date
Adding binary /sbin/hwclock
Adding binary /sbin/dumpe2fs
Adding library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libext2fs.so.2
Adding library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2
Adding library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libe2p.so.2
Calling hook fuse
Adding binary /sbin/mount.fuse
```

And finally

```
Calling hook klibc
Calling hook kmod
Adding binary /bin/kmod
cp: can't create '/tmp/mkinitramfs_6tXmAg/sbin/modprobe': File exists
cp: can't create '/tmp/mkinitramfs_6tXmAg/sbin/rmmod': File exists
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/kmod failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic with 1.
```

So I guess it is not using the usual binaries but others from busybox. if I run "man dpkg", I do see that the --compare-versions is there.

I would appreciate any help.